# How do I breed an Obsidian dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I just noticed that a new "Obsidian Dragon" has been added to the marketplace. What is the best combination of dragons to breed it.  My definition of "best" is a combination which yields the fastest successful result when averaged across attempts.  I can see in the marketplace that the breeding time is 8 hours, which is 6 hours 24 minutes with the upgraded BC/EBI.  Are there any other dragons with this same breeding time? (ie can I determine that I have bred this dragon successfully based on breeding time?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Obsidian Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Obsidian_Dragon) can be obtained by breeding an Earth Dragon or earth hybrid dragon with a Fire Dragon or a fire hybrid dragon. Its breeding time is 8 hours, or 6 hours 24 minutes if you have an upgraded breeding cave or island.

Bear in mind that breeding an Earth Dragon or earth hybrid dragon with a Fire Dragon or a fire hybrid dragon can also yield a Lava Dragon or, before Halloween, a limited edition Bone Dragon, both of which have breeding times of 10 hours, or 8 hours with the upgrade.

As for the best combination, breeding in DragonVale relies a lot on randomness. There is no canonical "best" combination for most dragons. No one seems to know for certain the odds of each outcome from every combination. However, according to this [DragonVale Breeding Sandbox](http://www.2084.org/dragonvale/breeding-sandbox/), the best combinations (without an Obsidian parent), with a success rate of 29%, would be:

- Bone and Mud
- Bone and Water
- Fire and Mud
- Lava and Water

Considering some of these combinations, it would seem all you really need is to have the earth and fire elements.

Comment: This is a really excellent answer, thanks for taking the time.  I recognize there are several equivalent "bests" in this case, but that short list was what I was looking for.  I did not realize till reading your answer that the Sandbox could be used for both average breed time and average success rate.  Since Obsidian is "uncommon", I think the pairs you list are far better than a Fire + Earth pairing which has a 25% success rate and an average fail time of 10 hours.

Comment: The average fail time of 8.37 hrs for the above pairs means that most folks will get the dragon an average of ~15 hours faster with this approach, and that assumes no downtime.  Based on Meta discussion, I was going to try and write a perfect answer - but thanks to yours that's not necessary.  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Got 1 with an earth dragon and a paper dragon, 8 hours.

Comment: It's been established that the columns pretty much make no difference in breeding, so you don't have to worry about which parent is on which side.

Answer (score 0):

You breed the Obsidian Dragon from Earth and Fire elements (i.e. Earth and Fire Dragon or their hybrids).

There is more information and data here: [Obsidian Dragon on Dragonvale Breeding Guide](http://www.dragonvalebreedingguide.com/dragon/obsidian-dragon/tips-hints)

Comment: Got a link for that?

Comment: No, that's just wrong.

Comment: For the sake of argument, I believe it is actually possible with Earth Hybrid + Air (and possibly Air Hybrid + Earth), because Air has a low chance of breeding as Fire or Water.  Earth+Air is of course impossible, so poorly worded at best.

Comment: Sorry, wrote the wrong element, it's Earth and Fire not Air.

Answer (score 0):

I used BONE and STORM. Got it on first try...